# How to get Message-ID from SwiftMailer in Yii2 after compose?

Tags: yii2, smtp, swiftmailer

I send emails this way:

```
    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('fromaddress@email.com')
        ->setTo('toaddress@email.com')
        ->setSubject('Testing Message-ID')
        ->setHtmlBody('Test')
        ->send();
```

How can I get Message-ID from $message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

```
$messageId = $message->getSwiftMessage()->getId();
```